# Dependency Property dependent on another

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, linkage

How can one register a dependency property whose value is calculated using the value of another dependency property?

Because the .NET property wrappers are bypassed by WPF at run-time, one should not include logic in the getters and setters.  The solution to that is typically to use `PropertyChangedCallback`s.  But those are declared static.

For example, what is the proper way to accomplish this contrived task:

```
public bool TestBool
{
  get { return (bool)GetValue(TestBoolProperty); }
  set 
  { 
    SetValue(TestBoolProperty, value);
    TestDouble = ((value)?(100.0):(200.0)); // HERE IS THE DEPENDENCY
  }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty TestBoolProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("TestBool", typeof(bool), typeof(ViewModel));

public double TestDouble
{
  get { return ((double)GetValue(TestDoubleProperty)); }
  set { SetValue(TestDoubleProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty TestDoubleProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("TestDouble", typeof(double), typeof(ViewModel));
```

As long as the dependency is not circular, is there a proper means to accomplish this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Hmmm... I think you'd better look at dependency properties [value coercion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795(v=vs.100).aspx). Here is an example with coercion:

```
public class ViewModel : DependencyObject
{
  public bool TestBool
  {
    get { return (bool)GetValue(TestBoolProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TestBoolProperty, value); }
  }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty TestBoolProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("TestBool", typeof(bool), typeof(ViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnTestBoolPropertyChanged));

  private static void OnTestBoolPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var vm = (ViewModel)d;
    vm.CoerceValue(TestDoubleProperty);
  }

  public double TestDouble
  {
    get { return ((double)GetValue(TestDoubleProperty)); }
    set { SetValue(TestDoubleProperty, value); }
  }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty TestDoubleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("TestDouble", typeof(double), typeof(ViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(0.0, null, OnCoerceTestDouble));

  private static object OnCoerceTestDouble(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
  {
    var vm = (ViewModel) d;
    var testBool = vm.TestBool;
    return ((testBool) ? (100.0) : (200.0));
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the advantage of using a `CoerceValueCallback` as you have done versus directly changing a dependency property from within another dependency property's `PropertyChangedCallback` as opedog did?  I gather from the documentation you linked that yours is the more proper method, but I am curious about the practical difference.

Comment: Well, to name couple: it doesn't break bindings to this property (i.e. if this property is a target of binding expression it will work after coercing but will be lost after explicit set); it has higher priority in dependency property value resolution (i.e. if you say PropA = "Something" that doesn't mean that PropA == "Something", since coercion could ignore that assignment); It remembers the old value of your property (i.e. next time you call CoerceValue() you will get original value of TestDouble, not the one that was set locally)

Answer (score 1):

You're actually correct, you should use PropertyChangedCallback.  Here's how:

```
public bool TestBool
{
  get { return (bool)GetValue(TestBoolProperty); }
  set 
  { 
    SetValue(TestBoolProperty, value);
  }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty TestBoolProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("TestBool", typeof(bool), typeof(ViewModel),
  new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTestBoolChanged)));

private static void OnTestBoolChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  ViewModel vm = d as ViewModel;
  vm.TestDouble = value ? 100.0 : 200.0;
}

public double TestDouble
{
  get { return ((double)GetValue(TestDoubleProperty)); }
  set { SetValue(TestDoubleProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty TestDoubleProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("TestDouble", typeof(double), typeof(ViewModel));
```

Comment: Thank you opedog.  In my investigation, I foolishly failed to examine what was passed into the `PropertyChangedCallback`.  I adjusted my test project to use this method and it's working.  I'm going to try Anvaka's solution next.